Error: no layers found when parsing zipped shp file in shpjs
I am working with vue3 to load a zipped shp file from a sample dataset found in the repository, https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/shapefile-js/blob/gh-pages/files/counties5.zip
The shp library used is https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/shapefile-js. shpjs 's version is "^5.0.1".
export async function loadGeojson(file: File): Promise<FeatureCollection<any>> {
    const format = file.name.split('.').at(-1).toLowerCase();
    let geojson: FeatureCollection<any>;
    switch (format) {
      case 'zip': {
        const parsed = await shp(await file.raw.arrayBuffer());
        geojson = parsed;
        break;
      }

but the code runs with an error:
shpjs.js?v=9c11b5bb:6989 Uncaught (in promise) Error: no layers founds
    at parseZip (shpjs.js?v=9c11b5bb:6989:11)
    at async Module.loadGeojson (shp.ts:55:24)
    at async Proxy.uploadFile (upload.vue:146:13)

